# How to read all the variables with a particular dimension or dimensions?

Tags: r, apply, netcdf, sapply, netcdf4

I have a netCDF file where there are

```
5 dimensions (a,b,c,d,e)
100 variables (x1,...,x100)
```

with the variables having different combinations of dimensions.

```
outx <- nc_open('testH.nc') #Open the NetCDF file
varx <- names(outx[['var']]) #Get all the variables
```

And I read all the variables using this:

```
t <- sapply(varx, function(x) ncvar_get(outx, x), USE.NAMES = TRUE)
```

But, I only want to read variables corresponding to `x` and `y` dimensions together.

How can I do this?